# Solr 1.4: No commit with custom UpdateRequestProcessorFactory

Tags: solr, processor, dih

I use an UpdateRequestProcessorChain in DIH and get the problem that the data isn't committed to the index. I tried to debug my Processor and it works. The status of the full-import command is:

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
    <int name="status">0</int>
    <int name="QTime">1</int>
</lst>
<lst name="initArgs">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="update.processor">DataImportChain</str>
        <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
</lst>
<str name="command">status</str>
<str name="status">idle</str>
<str name="importResponse"/>
<lst name="statusMessages">
    <str name="Total Requests made to DataSource">0</str>
    <str name="Total Rows Fetched">7</str>
    <str name="Total Documents Skipped">0</str>
    <str name="Full Dump Started">2012-04-26 17:47:44</str>
    <str name="">Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 6 documents. Deleted 0 documents.</str>
    <str name="Committed">2012-04-26 17:47:45</str>
    <str name="Optimized">2012-04-26 17:47:45</str>
    <str name="Total Documents Processed">6</str>
    <str name="Time taken ">0:0:1.174</str>
</lst>
<str name="WARNING">This response format is experimental.  It is likely to change in the future.</str>
```

But there is no information in catalina.out that the commit process was called:

```
26.04.2012 17:47:44 org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter doFullImport
INFO: Starting Full Import
26.04.2012 17:47:44 org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
INFO: [dev] webapp=/solr path=/dataimport params={clean=true&commit=true&command=full-import} status=0 QTime=20 
26.04.2012 17:47:44 org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SolrWriter readIndexerProperties
INFO: Read dataimport.properties
26.04.2012 17:47:45 org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.XPathEntityProcessor initXpathReader
INFO: Using xslTransformer: com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl
26.04.2012 17:47:45 org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder finish
INFO: Import completed successfully
26.04.2012 17:47:45 org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SolrWriter readIndexerProperties
INFO: Read dataimport.properties
26.04.2012 17:47:45 org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SolrWriter persist
INFO: Wrote last indexed time to dataimport.properties
26.04.2012 17:47:45 org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder execute
INFO: Time taken = 0:0:1.174
```

There aren't any errors in the logs. If I use the DIH without UpdateRequestProcessorChain there is no problem with commit. Has anybody an idea what could be wrong here?

Here is the configuration from my solrconfig.xml:

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="update.processor">DataImportChain</str>
        <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>  
    </lst>
</requestHandler>

<updateRequestProcessorChain name="DataImportChain" >
    <processor class="my.package.MyProcessorFactory" />
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

Comment: What do you mean by: "I use an UpdateRequestProcessorChain in DIH"? Could you post the chain configuration please?

Comment: @javanna I added the chain configuration from the solrconfig.xml above. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You left out some basics processors in your `updateRequestProcessorChain`, that's why nothing happens. Try this configuration:

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="DataImportChain" >
    <processor class="my.package.MyProcessorFactory" />
    <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
    <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

The `RunUpdateProcessorFactory` is in fact the one which does the "ordinary stuff" within the chain. If you forget it you are preprocessing something that is never indexed.

Comment: I tried this configuration and it works. Thank you for your help!